# Josephus Flavius task on linkedList with iterator

Tags: java, collections

I have two methods that solve J.F. task in two ways - 1st is without iterator, 2nd with iterator. But variant with iterator with LindedList must show better performance compared to ArrayList with iterator I guess. I think the problem is in the implementation of the method. So how to change it to make it perform better?

```
public static void removeOnContainer(List<Object> list, int k) {

    int index = 0;

    while (list.size() != 1) {
        index = (index + k - 1) % list.size();
        list.remove(index);
    }

}

public static void removeOnIterator(List<Object> list, int k) {

    Iterator<Object> iterator;
    int index = 0;

    while (list.size() != 1) {
        iterator = list.iterator();
        index = (index + k - 1) % list.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            iterator.next();
        }
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to know about performance, **measure**. Various optimizations may let you end up with unexpected results and it is hard to guess what the performance of a specific piece of code is going to be without running it. So what have you measured?

Comment: Anyhow, your iterator example has 1:1 ratio between taking an iterator and calling remove on it. Would it be possible to use one iterator for multiple removes? (wink, wink)

Comment: @jakub_d I measured time during which the algorithm will find a winning position of a certain amount

Comment: How to get good answers: add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the measurement that demonstrates the performance, which people could run for themselves and try to make faster.